# Which sales_rep has Which account for Which months

Tags: postgresql-10

This is a sample of my history table, named 'sales_rep_account_mgmt_hist':

```
account_id sales_rep date_modified      
---------- --------- -------------------
1205       chloe     2019-01-15 09:17:32
1205       elisabeth 2019-06-15 09:17:32
1205       chloe     2019-08-01 07:55:03
1205       elisabeth 2020-01-02 08:04:52
1205       rachael   2020-01-04 16:22:32
1206       elisabeth 2019-08-28 13:14:12
1206       chloe     2019-10-26 07:37:22
1206       rachael   2019-10-29 09:22:56
```

I would like a query on this table to return year and month each sales rep managed accounts:

```
account_id sales_rep  Yr  Mo
---------- --------- ---- --
1205       chloe     2019 01
1205       chloe     2019 02
1205       chloe     2019 03
1205       chloe     2019 04
1205       chloe     2019 05
1205       chloe     2019 08
1205       chloe     2019 09
1205       chloe     2019 10
1205       chloe     2019 11
1205       chloe     2019 12
1205       elisabeth 2019 06
1205       elisabeth 2019 07
1205       rachael   2020 01
1206       elisabeth 2019 08
1206       elisabeth 2019 09
1206       rachael   2019 10
1206       rachael   2019 11
1206       rachael   2019 12
1206       rachael   2020 01
```

I've tried this: (dimdate is a date table)

```
with cte as (
    select b.account_id, b.sales_rep, b.dt_mod, b.year_actual, b.month_actual, (b.year_actual::text || lpad(b.month_actual::text,2,'0')) as yr_mo
    from(
            select a.account_id, ram.sales_rep, a.dt_mod, a.year_actual, a.month_actual
            from( 
                    select account_id, max(date_modified)as dt_mod, d.year_actual, d.month_actual
                    from sales_rep_account_mgmt_hist m

                    join test_schema.dimdate d
                    on extract(year from m.date_modified) = d.year_actual and extract(month from m.date_modified) = d.month_actual

                    where m.date_modified between '2019-01-01' and '2020-02-01'
                    group by account_id, d.year_actual, d.month_actual

            )a join sales_rep_account_mgmt_hist ram on a.dt_mod = ram.date_modified
    )b
), cte2 as (
    select year_actual as year_, month_actual as month_, (year_actual::text || lpad(month_actual::text,2,'0')) as yr_mo
    from dimdate dd 
    where dd.date_actual between '2019-01-01' and '2020-02-01'
)
    select distinct cte.account_id, cte.sales_rep, cte.dt_mod, cte.year_actual, cte.month_actual,cte2.year_, cte2.month_, cte2.yr_mo
    from cte join cte2 on cte.yr_mo >= cte2.yr_mo
```

This seems like a step in the right direction but far from getting it done. I'm stumped :-\

A new row is created in the 'sales_rep_account_mgmt_hist' table above whenever a trigger fires on a certain production table. An inserted or updated row in the production table creates a copy of that row in the history table. **The production table has account_id + sales_rep as its primary key.** So the production table can't have more than one row for chloe with account 1205, for example, but the history table above can and so the reason for this table.

So for a supplied date range of 2019-01-01 until 2020-02-01, Chloe is managing 1205 from 1/2019 through 5/2019. Elisabeth takes over 6/2019 until Chloe picks it up again 8/2019 and continues until Rachael takes over 1/2020. Elisabeth managed it briefly in 1/2020 but **only the sales rep who managed it last in the month gets counted**. Date_modified indicates when a sales rep begins managing an account.

Comment: I don't understand what `date_created` is supposed to represent. For `chloe` there are two identical rows for account 1205, both created at the same timestamp in January. Assuming date_created, date_modified indicates some kind of range, then where do the months 11 and 12 come from for chloe? And why isn't 6 and 7 not included for her? The second row would include those two monts

Comment: I should have left date_created out since it is not relevant here. I'll remove that. Chloe's two identical rows will not look so identical when date_created is removed - see date_modified. Date_modified indicates when a sales_rep began managing an account.